# select if a number is contained between a range

Tags: r

```
refDat <- structure(list(CatMin = c(0L, 17L, 28L, 34L, 48L, 64L, 120L
                    ), CatMax = c(16L, 27L, 33L, 47L, 63L, 119L, 160L), correctionRef = c(0L, 
                    0L, 0L, 0L, -5L, -15L, -40L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to select row in which 30 lies between `CatMin` & `CatMax`. In the above example, it lies in 3rd row

```
with(refDat, CatMax <= 30 & CatMin >= 30)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# However, it is returning all the FALSE to me.
```

Comment: Did you accidentally reverse your greater than & less than? Because right now you're checking that 30 is greater than your maximum value *and* less than your minimum value, and I think you want the reverse. The one row you'd expect to return true is (28, 33), but you're checking that 30 is both less than 28 and greater than 33

Comment: As camille pointed out: `with(refDat, CatMax >= 30 & CatMin <= 30)`?

Comment: @camille You are right, but you seem to have overlooked that this is addressed in my answer, see below.

Comment: @RHertel if it's a typo/accident, it should be closed as such, even if an answer points out the typo

Comment: @camille Not a typo, but a mistake in the logics. There are countless such questions on SO, which deserve to be answered. In any case, your comment appears to be redundant because there were already answers pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @RHertel OP has about 200 questions with R tag. This is either a duplicate or a typo, and deserves no answers.

Comment: @RHertel unless there was a reason to think 28 is greater than 30, it really doesn't seem like the issue is one of programming logic, but just of mixing up the order to write out 28 <= 30 <= 33. If there's something deeper going on, maybe the OP can clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
refDat %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 filter(between(30, CatMin, CatMax))

  CatMin CatMax correctionRef
   <int>  <int>         <int>
1     28     33             0
```

Alternatively, you can also use `between()` from `data.table`, which is vectorized:

```
refDat %>%
 filter(data.table::between(30, CatMin, CatMax))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was almost correct, but the logics of your comparisons did not match. Try this:

```
refDat[with(refDat, CatMin <= 30 &  CatMax >= 30),]
# CatMin CatMax correctionRef
# 3     28     33             0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this `apply`.

```
apply(refDat[1:2], 1, function(x) 30 %in% seq(x[1], x[2]))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```